# JasperReports - Text File contains 2 Newline characters at the end of every page

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm new to JasperReports and am struggling with this one issue.  I have searched for answers to this problem, but have not had any luck finding one (most seemingly relevant comments relate to XLS exports and missing data).
 For this example, I have removed every section except detail (I still have the same problem when Page/Column Headers, etc. are included).  The page is breaking at the correct line count (66 lines/page in this setup), but there are 2 extra newlines after every page break.  They are not "blank lines" because those are padded out to the Page Width (133 columns ~ 1330 pixels at 10 width), these are just additional x'0D0A' and I can't get rid of them.

Here is the JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TextReport" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" pageWidth="1330" pageHeight="792" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.width" value="10"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.character.height" value="12"/>
    <style name="FixSizeFontStyle" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" fontSize="10"/>
    <parameter name="QueryString" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[$P!{QueryString}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PRSN_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="12">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="25" y="0" width="100" height="12"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRSN_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And here is how I'm running it (actual query obfuscated):

```
Map<String, Object> jaspParms = new HashMap<String, Object>();
jaspParms.put("QueryString", "SELECT * FROM table where col > value");
JasperReport jaspReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathJRXML);
JasperPrint jaspPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jaspReport, jaspParms, conDB);
JRTextExporter jaspTextExport = new JRTextExporter();
jaspTextExport.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jaspPrint));
jaspTextExport.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(pathText));
jaspTextExport.exportReport();
```

Here is the end of the page, note the spaces padding out - this is line 66 and is expected:

[image: Here]

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Write this property into your source file (jrxml file)

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.page.separator" value=""/>
```

Comment: HI Pablo, great to have you here as new contributor. Our profession thrives on sharing. Could you improve you answer by adding a sentence or two, explaining what the setting you suggest does. Will help a lot